Creating a new DataFrame column from application of function to multiple columns in groupby
I have a DataFrame of population counts by combination of categorical demographic features and date, with some missing values (consistent across all combos) per date constituting gaps in the data.
I am attempting to:

group by all demographic features
apply a function to each time series of population counts per demographic group (this requires manipulating both the date column and the population column)
create a new column in the original (ungrouped) DataFrame based on this function

The function in (2) acts on the existing population column with missing values, redistributing post-gap counts backwards over the gap. I believe the function works as intended, but I am struggling to stitch it into the context of the group-by and turn that into a new column in the DataFrame.
Here is sample data:
          age          race     gender         date       population
0       15-24          AAPI       Male   2020-01-01              1.0   
1       15-24          AAPI       Male   2020-01-02              2.0
2       15-24          AAPI       Male   2020-01-03              2.0
... 
7       15-24         Black     Female   2020-01-01              0.0   
8       15-24         Black     Female   2020-01-02              NaN
9       15-24         Black     Female   2020-01-03              3.0     

For the above trivial example, the desired output would be:
          age          race     gender         date       population   interpolated
0       15-24          AAPI       Male   2020-01-01              1.0            1.0   
1       15-24          AAPI       Male   2020-01-02              2.0            2.0
2       15-24          AAPI       Male   2020-01-03              2.0            2.0
... 
7       15-24         Black     Female   2020-01-01              0.0            0.0   
8       15-24         Black     Female   2020-01-02              NaN            1.5
9       15-24         Black     Female   2020-01-03              3.0            1.5     

I have created the following function, which takes an input list of date gaps:
gaps = [
    {
        "gap": [2020-01-02],
        "day_after": 2020-01-03,
    }
]

def bfill_pop(gaps, group):
    for el in gaps:
        fill_val = group.loc[group["date"] == el["day_after"], "population"] / (
            len(el["gap"]) + 1
        )
        group.loc[group["date"].isin(el["gap"]), "population"] = fill_val
        group.loc[group["date"] == el["day_after"], "population"] = fill_val
    return group.rename(columns={"population": "interpolated"})["interpolated"]

When I try to apply this to the DataFrame with apply() or transform() functions though, I get errors, e.g.:
df["interpolated"] = df.groupby(["age", "race", "gender"]).apply(
    lambda g: bfill_pop(gaps, g)
)

> ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

Is there a way to do this with apply or transform functions?

what is the "Admissions" you are referencing? I am trying to run your code, but throws an error at that point

@iBeMeltin sorry updated to the correct populations (code is adapted from elsewhere).

Are the date gaps data calculated from the input data as well? It seems like gaps above only applies to the second group

@ELinda the gaps can be treated like a fixed input, their calculation is not part of this problem—they just need to be applied to the grouped DataFrame.

What I meant is why are interpolated values in rows 7-9 divided by 2 as opposed to the other rows?

You were nearly there. It was simply a miss-handling of indices in the function:
import pandas as pd

def bfill_pop(gaps, group):
    for el in gaps:
        day_after_population = group.loc[group['date'] == pd.to_datetime(el['day_after']), 'population']
        if not day_after_population.empty:
            fill_val = day_after_population.iloc[0] / (len(el['gap']) + 1)
            group.loc[group['date'].isin([pd.to_datetime(date) for date in el['gap']]), 'population'] = fill_val
            group.loc[group['date'] == pd.to_datetime(el['day_after']), 'population'] = fill_val
    return group

data = {
    'age': ['15-24'] * 6,
    'race': ['AAPI', 'AAPI', 'Black', 'Black', 'Black', 'Black'],
    'gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female'],
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03']),
    'population': [1.0, 2.0, 0.0, np.nan, np.nan, 3.0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

gaps = [
    {
        "gap": ['2020-01-02'],
        "day_after": '2020-01-03',
    }
]

df['interpolated'] = df.groupby(['age', 'race', 'gender']).apply(
    lambda g: bfill_pop(gaps, g)
).reset_index(drop=True)['population']  

print(df)


which gives you
     age   race  gender       date  population  interpolated
0  15-24   AAPI    Male 2020-01-01         1.0           1.0
1  15-24   AAPI    Male 2020-01-02         2.0           2.0
2  15-24  Black  Female 2020-01-01         0.0           0.0
3  15-24  Black  Female 2020-01-02         NaN           1.5
4  15-24  Black  Female 2020-01-02         NaN           1.5
5  15-24  Black  Female 2020-01-03         3.0           1.5

